# Can snowflake spark connector create external table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Please let me know whether [Snowflake Spark connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html) has the ability to create Snowflake external table?

Answer (score 0):

Spark connector does support DDL statement and CREAT EXTERNAL TABLE is a DDL statement

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#executing-ddl-dml-sql-statements

Comment: thanks @Iqra, however, I can't find an example of external table creation on the page you mentioned, would be good if there is something like this on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how you can create external tables with spark connector, but, what I usually do is to create a stage in snowflake using a Blob Storage or S3 Bucket and you can work it like a local file. Which can be use in your queries using spark connector, also, any new file on the stage (BlobStorage/S3 Bucket) will be available through a query such as:

```
SELECT *  FROM @"STAGE_NAME"/example.json;
```

I ain't sure if this is of any help, I don't know how you are trying to apply it. But if it does, I'll be glad to put a example here.

Comment: I end up creating a tool by myself which does not use spark connector (instead python connector). Thanks anyway :)